# Stumped implementing express-session variables as an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to grok Express here. I'm using the express-session module and I've had no trouble when I'm using session variables that are objects or strings. However, I just can't seem to get arrays to work. I'm using the shopping cart technique as a lab rat. Here's the code that's causing me problems:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.action == 'Add to Cart') {
        var cart = req.session.cart = [];       
        cart.push(req.body.itemId);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        if (req.session.cart) {
            var itemsInCart = req.session.cart.length;
        }
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Shopping Spree',
            itemsInCart: itemsInCart,
            products: [
                {id: 1, item: 'Boeing 747', price: 4500},
                {id: 2, item: 'Luxury Yacht', price: 200},
                {id: 3, item: 'Mercedes AMG GT', price: 15000},
                {id: 4, item: 'Apple iPhone 6', price: 2400},
                {id: 5, item: 'Moet Hennessey', price: 5000}
            ]

        });
    });
```

And in the view: `index.jade`:

```
extends layout
block content
    h2= title
    p Cart(#{itemsInCart} items) 
        a(href="/cart") [VIEW CART]

    table
        thead
            tr
                th Item
                th Price
            tr
        tbody
        - for (var i in products) {
            tr
                td= products[i].item
                td= products[i].price
                td
                    form(action="/", method="post")
                        input(type="hidden", name="itemId" value="#{products[i].id}")
                        input(type="submit", name="action", value="Add to Cart")
        - }
```

The first time the 'Add to Cart' button is clicked, `itemsInCart` is indeed updated to 1. Subsequent 'Add to Cart' clicks won't update that value.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Using this line

```
var cart = req.session.cart = [];
```

each time you call it, you redefine content of req.session.cart to [].

Try instead:

```
var cart = req.session.cart || [];
```

It will keep existing value of `cart` and you will not loose previous items

**UPDATE**

As for updated question, here is what you can do, to keep Jade's bindings updated:

```
var pageScope;

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.action == 'Add to Cart') {
        var cart = req.session.cart = [];
        cart.push(req.body.itemId);
        pageScope.itemsInCart = req.session.cart && req.session.cart;
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    pageScope.itemsInCart = req.session.cart && req.session.cart;
    res.render('index', pageScope = {
       //...
    });
});
```

Idea is to update `itemsInCart`, every time, you increase the length of `cart` array.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I've tried it out, itemsInCart stays at 0 and won't update.

Comment: That means that piece of code that is responsible for update, is not runing after item add, please give more info on where this itemsInCart variable is being defined?

Comment: I've edited my question, adding all the relevant code. Please check it out.

Comment: Variables within an if statement exist outside the if statement if it is truthy. Might want to reword the last part.

Comment: @BenFortune, thanks, tried better one, hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried everything. Still not working. @jevgenig, thanks for the help, though. Your answer taught me a few new tricks.

Comment: @jevgenig, I found the solution! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many, many iterations, I finally got it to work:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.cart) {
        var itemsInCart = req.session.cart.length;
    } else {
        req.session.cart = [];
    }
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Shopping Spree',
        itemsInCart: itemsInCart,
        //...   
    });
});
```

then

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.action == 'Add to Cart') {
        req.session.cart.push(req.body.itemId);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

I just don't know why I hadn't thought of this earlier. Must be one of my bad days.